# How long do grenade donations take to explode?

Tags: fallout-4

If I reverse-pickpocket a grenade using the [second rank of the Pickpocket perk](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pickpocket), how many seconds does it take for the live grenade to detonate?

Additionally, does the perk only work for fragmentation grenades, or do other grenade types work?

Comment: I haven't bought the perk, so I haven't been able to try it, but in past games any explosive worked (plasma grenade, dynamite, landmines, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any kind of grenade can be used when planting a grenade. Once placed into the pockets of your victim to be, the item description will change to "Live " - upon closing the trade screen the victim will be marked with the grenade proximity warning and will explode after 3 seconds.

Comment: What about Molotovs?

Comment: Are Molotovs actually a grenade as such rather than just another thrown items? I will need to test, might as well check mines while we're at it

Comment: Oooh, Molotovs should be fun. I seriously need that perk now.

Comment: fwiw molotovs explode the same way but will leave behind its usual lingering burning effect for a few seconds.  And also Strong really likes it when you leave 'gifts' like this, very easy to get his admiration up that way.

Comment: How about relay grenades, or artillery grenades?